# React - How to hide register/login in navbar once a user has logged in?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to be able to hide the links to register and log in once a user has logged in. I'm using react.

Here are the links in my nav:

```
<Navbar>
 <Nav.Item>
            <Nav.Link href="/Register">Register</Nav.Link>
          </Nav.Item>
          <Nav.Item>
            <Nav.Link href="/Login">Login</Nav.Link>
          </Nav.Item>
</Navbar>
```

I'm using local storage for the login:

```
localStorage.setItem("userID", user);
```

Answer (score 2):

you can get the item with localStorage.getItem('userID') and use it to hide the links

```
<Navbar>
          {!localStorage.getItem('userID') && (
            <Nav.Item>
          
              <Nav.Link href="/Register">Register</Nav.Link>
            </Nav.Item>
            <Nav.Item>
              <Nav.Link href="/Login">Login</Nav.Link>
            </Nav.Item>
          )}
</Navbar>
```

this way the links will only be displayed if localStorage.getItem('userID') is undefined or has any falsy value